# Storing objects in session; not getting proper output

Tags: php, oop, session

I am trying to store objects in session

However, when I do the following, I don't get output as expected

**Code:**

In the session am storing objects like this -

```
    $oEmployee = new Employee();
    $_SESSION['Employee'] = $oEmployee;
```

And am trying to print like this -

```
    print_r($_SESSION['Employee']);
    echo "<br>";
    $oEmployee = new $_SESSION['Employee'];
    print_r($oEmployee);
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
    Employee Object
    (
       [m_sFirstName:private] => Sac
       [m_sLastName:private] => Kos
       [m_sPhone:private] => 9876543210
       [m_sEmail:private] => sac@kos.com
       [m_sPassword:private] => password
       [m_iEmployeeId:private] => 1 
    )

    Employee Object
    (
       [m_sFirstName:private] => 
       [m_sLastName:private] => 
       [m_sPhone:private] => 
       [m_sEmail:private] => 
       [m_sPassword:private] => 
    )
```

Any idea what's going wrong ?

Comment: try `serialize` the object before storing it to session and for retrieving it use `unserilize`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your line

```
$oEmployee = new $_SESSION['Employee'];
```

PHP casts the value in `$_SESSION['Employee']` to string, and then tries to instantiate a class with that name (`new`).  Since you aren't passing anything to the constructor, an empty object is instantiated.

What are you *trying* to do in that line?

Comment: That's right! I don't know what I was trying to do! Actually it should be just like $oEmployee = $_SESSION['Employee']; Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize object before write it to the session:

```
$oEmployee = new Employee();
$_SESSION['Employee'] = serialize($oEmployee);
```

After that you can get it by following code:

```
$Employee = unserialize($_SESSION['Employee']);
```